# How can I add NA values to empty rows within a loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

I am tasked with creating a loop that does a few things:

1. Eliminates rows with missing data for the "height" variable
2. Selects the first visit available (already ordered beforehand)
3. Appends the remaining value for "height" for a partcular patient in a dataframe

Essentially, the goal is to obtain the first non-missing height value from a set of observations within each patient. Every patient has different amounts of observations and "missingness" so I was advised to create a loop for this task

This is my attempt:

```
for (i in 1:length(patients)){

# select data for one patient
patient = patients[i]
SubjectID_patient = filter(DF, Subject.ID == patient)

#select data which is not missing
complete_hts=filter(SubjectID_patient,
!is.na(SubjectID_patient$height_cm))

#select first visit for height
complete_hts=complete_hts[!duplicated(complete_hts$Subject.ID),]

# if there are 0 entries remaining, return NAs
????

#make dataframe for the patient
df_patient = data.frame(Subject.ID = complete_hts$Subject.ID,
                        height =  complete_hts$height_cm)

##bind rows of this dataframe to first dataframe
baseline_new = rbind(baseline_new, df_patient)

}
```

So as you can see, I'm  stuck at the part where if there are 0 entries for a particular patient for the "height" variable, return NAs. The loop works fine until I encounter a visit where there are 0 valid values and because of this I cannot create a dataframe in the end. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Please pardon my improper formatting (if any) as this is my first post on stackoverflow!

Thanks!

Comment: You can remove all rows where height is na by running dat[!is.na(dat$height),] and then update your patient list to what's left in the data.frame and then you're set. You could probably do this without a for loop and it would be faster though.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only NAs in SubjectID_patient$height_cm, then complete_hts should be empty data.frame and nrow(complete_hts) should be equal to 0. You can use if statement based on that:

```
if (nrow(complete_hts)!=0) {
#select first visit for height
complete_hts=complete_hts[!duplicated(complete_hts$Subject.ID),]
} else {
complete_hts$height_cm=NA
}

#make dataframe for the patient
df_patient = data.frame(Subject.ID = complete_hts$Subject.ID,
                    height =  complete_hts$height_cm)

##bind rows of this dataframe to first dataframe
baseline_new = rbind(baseline_new, df_patient)
}
```